# AWS Lambda Java done() Method

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-lib

I don't see a done() method in the Context object of the Java implementation of AWS lambda.

In node, you can perform a bunch of async operations and then call done() when everything has completed.  The lambda is considered unfinished until done() is called.

I would like to do something similar in Java, but I don't see the done() method.  So then when is a Java implementation of a lambda function considered "done"?  When it returns?  Do I have to instead block on everything before returning?  That seems crumby.

Answer (score 0):

From the "Getting Started: Authoring AWS Lambda Code in Java" page of the documentation, http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/java-gs.html:

You just return a string when done.  Deciding when you're "done" is up to you, i.e. if you issue asynchronous calls you have to ensure they've completed.

`package example;
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.Context; 
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.LambdaLogger;
public class Hello {
    public String myHandler(int myCount, Context context) {
        LambdaLogger logger = context.getLogger();
        logger.log("received : " + myCount);
        return String.valueOf(myCount);
    }
}`